# s3fs does not store downloaded files in the specified cache directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

I created a s3 bucket and mounted it locally using s3fs with `-ouse_cache=/tmp` as option. I copied a 50MB zip to the mounted directory and it got uploaded to s3. Then I tried to copy that s3fs file to another directory. It immediately got copied without any downloads. I thought it might be because I have specified a local cache directory and it might be present in it so that it can avoid downloads. But there were no files present in `/tmp` cache folder. Okay so maybe the s3fs file is persisted in the mounted directory, so that's why it is not present in cache. So I re-mounted the s3fs, hoping that this time I will see the downloads happening from s3 and files being cached in `/tmp`. But no it didn't happen, the zip file was copied without downloading anything and still there were no files in `/tmp`.

Next, I repeated the same after rebooting the PC. This time the file got downloaded for it to be copied. But again no cached files in `/tmp`. It seems that the s3fs files are cached in memory instead of local disk

Can you please tell why does this happen?

Comment: Which version of s3fs are you using?  When I mount with -ouse_cache and copy a local file to the s3fs mount, I see a cache file of the same size in the directory.